# Which preposition is the best for the word "priority"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know which preposition is the best for the sentence below;

> Set priorities of/for/to/on your tasks at work.

Comment: I won’t suggest this as an answer, because it doesn’t directly respond to your question, but here is a structure that circumvents the preposition issue all together: “**Prioritize** your tasks at work.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>for</kbd> would be best in this context.

> Set priorities **for** your tasks at work.

This is true for most contexts.

> Set your priorities for tasks at work.
>
> Setting priorities for tasks at work is very important.
>
> It is important to set priorities for tasks at work.

**A word of warning:** Don't blindly apply this rule to literally any context.

<kbd>Of</kbd> and <kbd>To</kbd> would never be used in any reasonable context.

Comment: The last **Set your priorities on the highway** is slightly off, as **on** is describing your location, not your priority. It is still "Set your priorities for safety or speed on the highway".

Comment: Yeah, it's a bad example. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: I gave one in the comment and +1 but suggest deleting the last two lines of the answer.

Comment: **Bold** might be better than the <kbd> tag to highlight words here.

Comment: @Davo I have a made-up convention where I reserve italic and bold for emphasis. I use block quote for sentences or paragraphs, code blocks for sentence fragments, and <kbd> for single words.